# Android - Animate width of View when AppBar scrolling

Tags: android, android-animation, android-appbarlayout

I want to make width of View has animation when AppBar scrolling, like below.

[image: gif]

How to do that? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe motion layout is easy way to go

Comment: How to animate width of view by percentage?

Comment: This will help you https://medium.com/@gilgoldzweig/how-to-perfect-android-animations-using-motionlayout-286cfa0f4f13

Comment: Thank for your answer. I will learn about it.
I'm taking a different approach, use ```binding.appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->```. It seems to be very difficult.